# Running golang tests on heroku

Tags: heroku, go

I more or less followed these instructions to deploy my app to heroku. Everything works well.

http://mmcgrana.github.io/2012/09/getting-started-with-go-on-heroku.html

I've got some benchmarking tests that I'd like to run on heroku to test whether or not there's a difference in performance between my local machine and the heroku box. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to run them (heroku can't find the go executable). Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Heroku. It's possible that Heroku has a problem running a benchmark using the `go test` command; there may be a problem with the temporary directory.

> [Command go](http://golang.org/cmd/go/)
>
> [Test packages](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages)
>
> 'Go test' recompiles each package along with any files with names
>   matching the file pattern "**test.go". Files whose names begin with
>   "*" (including "_test.go") or "." are ignored. These additional files
>   can contain test functions, benchmark functions, and example
>   functions. See 'go help testfunc' for more. Each listed package causes
>   the execution of a separate test binary.
>
> The package is built in a temporary directory so it does not interfere
>   with the non-test installation.

Try running the benchmark tests in a program. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "testing"
)

// a function to be benchmarked
func Area(r float64) float64 {
    return math.Pi * r * r
}

// benchmark function
func BenchmarkArea(b *testing.B) {
    r := 42.0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = Area(r)
    }
}

func main() {
    br := testing.Benchmark(BenchmarkArea)
    fmt.Println(br.String() + br.MemString())
}
```

Output:

```
2000000000           1.21 ns/op       0 B/op           0 allocs/op
```

> [Package testing](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/)
>
> [func Benchmark](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Benchmark)
>
> ```
> func Benchmark(f func(b *B)) BenchmarkResult
> ```
>
> Benchmark benchmarks a single function. Useful for creating custom
>   benchmarks that do not use the "go test" command.

Comment: The problem is that in my heroku deployment, I don't have access to the go executable. I don't know why that is. It's likely there and not in the path, but I don't know where it is.